# Windows SDK in Docker servercore container

Tags: windows, docker, command-line-interface, windows-server, signtool

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022

# other lines
```

I use containerized app for build *.msi* installer from Java app using **WIX toolset** which install using this command:

```
RUN Write-Host ('Downloading https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/releases/download/wix3112rtm/wix311.exe ...'); \
    curl.exe -LfsSo wix311.exe https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/releases/download/wix3112rtm/wix311.exe ; \
    Write-Host ('Verifying sha256 (32bb76c478fcb356671d4aaf006ad81ca93eea32c22a9401b168fc7471feccd2) ...'); \
    if ((Get-FileHash wix311.exe -Algorithm sha256).Hash -ne '32bb76c478fcb356671d4aaf006ad81ca93eea32c22a9401b168fc7471feccd2') { \
        Write-Host 'FAILED!'; \
        exit 1; \
    }; \
    \
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path C:\temp | Out-Null; \
    \
    Write-Host 'Installing using EXE ...'; \
    $proc2 = Start-Process -FilePath "wix311.exe" -ArgumentList '/quiet', -Wait -Passthru; \
    $proc2.WaitForExit() ; \
    Remove-Item -Path C:\temp -Recurse | Out-Null; \
    Write-Host 'Removing wix311.exe ...'; \
    Remove-Item wix311.exe -Force
```

And everything works well.

Now I need to use **signtool.exe** in this container. It is part of [Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/).

How to install in only using **CLI**?